# Docker container: MongoDb Insufficient free space for journal files

Tags: mongodb, docker

I am running MongoDB inside a Docker (version 1.10.1, on OSX) container and it is giving this error:

> MongoDb Insufficient free space for journal files

I am not able to find out weather the issue in on the host, the container, or in virtual box?

However, on my host I have:

```
Filesystem                          Size   Used  Avail Capacity  iused     ifree %iused  Mounted on
/dev/disk1                         465Gi   75Gi  389Gi    17% 19777401 102066309   16%   /
```

And on the docker container:

```
Filesystem      Inodes  IUsed  IFree IUse% Mounted on
none           1218224 742474 475750   61% /
```

I have also mounted a volume from the host with:

```
run -it -v /Users/foobar/Projects/compose:/data/db mongoImage:0.1 /bin/bash
```

Comment: Not a programming question. Should be on [SuperUser](http://superuser.com) or [ServerFault](http://serverfault.com)

Comment: There are 9200+ questions tagged `docker` on Stack Overflow compared to 649 and 177 on Server Fault and Super User. I'd say the community has spoken and Docker question on Stack Overflow are certainly valid. More so if you want any visibility on it...

Comment: A quick search reveals a number of issues relating to Docker and boot2docker on the issue. Your free space command if for inodes though (not disk space). Can you post the actual `df`? Also, from all the errors on the issue there is a second line with: `Please make at least 3379MB available in /data/db/journal or use --smallfiles`. Do you have another line explaining how much space you need free? There is also a solution right in the message and that is to use `--smallfiles`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the comments #andy, the issue did seem to be within the virtual box env.

I was able to resolve the issue by:

- backing up all docker images
- cloning the default virtual box iso (as
  a backup)
- deleting the default virtual box iso and all associated
  files.
- restarting docker, a new default Vbox iso was created. This
  resolved the issue (which I expect to have again at some point)